# error - unknown compression method (cordova, taco remotebuild)

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I get the following error message when I try to "remotebuild" a iphone application on a macbook pro:

> *"An error occured in extracting content from /'myhomefolder/.taco_home/../upload_4578.tgz': unknown compression method."*

Yesterday everything worked fine for me. This morning, without changing anything, the problem appeared.

Testing through "remotebuild test" on the MacBook works fine leaving a "taco-remote test passed". Extraction also seems to work.

The `../build/task/4578/cordovaApp` folder (for example) on the Mac side is empty. In the folders built yesterday you can find the typical folder structure of a Cordova app.

Visual Studio response is `"Error: Remote build error from the build server undefined"`.

Because I was able to deploy the application through Visual Studio 2015 on the remote device yesterday, I am a little lost at the moment.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall and then reinstall remotebuild in secure mode? if so, you must regenerate the certificates. If not, still try the following solution, remotebuild can not read the stream, it is certainly a certificate problem.

Solution:
remotebuild generate certificates

and enter the pin code in visual studio again

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is - but it is working again ... thank you for your help. at the moment i don`t have any time left to check what the real problem is ... we`ll see.

Comment: Have the same issue today. I ran non-secure connection and regenerated certificates anyway. Cleard cordova cache, rebuilded app, restarted mac. Problem still persistsm, "unknown compression method".